# Using Perl's File::Copy to rename a file extension

Tags: perl

How do I use `File::Copy` to rename a file extension?

So far, I can add an extension. I need to replace the file extension instead.

Example:
`myfilename.txt` to `myfilename.dat`

My code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Copy;

my ($oldfn) = qw (myfilename.txt);
my $newfn = $oldfn . ".dat";

rename($oldfn, $newfn)
   or die("Can't rename: $!\n");
```

Result: `myfilename.txt.dat`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use File::Basename's fileparse method to find the suffix, then do a search/replace.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use feature qw(say);
use File::Basename qw(fileparse);

my $oldfilename = "/foo/bar/baz.txt";

my($filename, $directories, $suffix) = fileparse($oldfilename,qr/\.[^.]*$/);

$filename =~ s/\.$suffix$//;

my $newfilename = $filename.".dat";

say "New filename is:".$newfilename;
say "New fullpath is:".$directories.$newfilename;

exit 0;
```

Output:

```
$ ./basename.pl
New filename is:baz.dat
New fullpath is:/foo/bar/baz.dat
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple regex will suffice:

```
$newfn = $oldfn;
$newfn =~ s/\.txt$/.dat/i;
```

Oh, you might also want to do:

```
use File::Copy qw(move);

...

move($oldfn, $newfn) or die...
```

Otherwise you are using Perl's built-in function [rename](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/rename.html).

Answer (score 1):

A little regex would do the job:

```
($new = $old) =~ s/[^.]+$/dat/;
rename $old, $new or die "Can't rename: $!\n";
```